# React, Express, Twitter oauth1.0a is sending 215 error

Tags: reactjs, express, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Currently I'm using Twitter's OAuth 1.0a.

1. Since Twitter doesn't allow CORS by itself, I'm trying to send request from Express server.
2. Since I'm using OAuth 1.0a I'm following https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens
3. To make a request, it says that I need to pass below information as authorization value inside header.

   1. oath_consumer_key
   2. oath_nonce
   3. oauth_signature_method
   4. oauth_timestamp
   5. oauth_version
   6. oauth_token
   7. oath_signature

then I got 215 error.

I tried to regenerate my API keys, tokens but still it throws 215 error.

Below is my code in Express:

```
const verifyTwitter = async(req,res) => {
    const API_BASE_URL = process.env.TWITTER_BASE_URL; // https://api.twitter.com/oauth
    const oauth_consumer_key = process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
    const oauth_consumer_key_secret = process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY;
    const oauth_token = process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN;
    const oauth_token_secret = process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET;
    const ACTION = '/request_token';

    let nonceLen = 32;
    const oauth_nonce =  crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(nonceLen * 3 / 4))
    .toString('base64') 
    .slice(0, nonceLen)       
    .replace(/\+/g, '0') 
    .replace(/\//g, '0');
    const method = 'POST';
    const oauth_timestamp = date.toUTCString();
    const oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1'
    const oauth_version = '1.0'

    const param_config = `oauth_consumer_key=${oauth_consumer_key}&oauth_nonce=${oauth_nonce}&oauth_signature_method=${oauth_signature_method}&oauth_timestamp=${oauth_timestamp}&oauth_token=${oauth_token}&oauth_version=${oauth_version}`


    const oauth_collection_data = `${method}&${API_BASE_URL}&${param_config}`;
    const sign_key = `${oauth_consumer_key_secret}&${oauth_token_secret}`;
    const oauth_signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1' , sign_key).update(oauth_collection_data).digest('base64')
    // const oauth_signature = hmac(sign_key,oauth_collection_data);



    const oAuthToken = await needle('post',API_BASE_URL + ACTION + `?oauth_consumer_key=${oauth_consumer_key}`,{},{
        headers : {
            authorization: `OAuth oauth_consumer_key=${oauth_consumer_key}, oauth_nonce=${oauth_nonce},  oauth_signature_method=${oauth_signature_method}, oauth_timestamp=${oauth_timestamp}, oauth_version=${oauth_version}, oauth_token=${oauth_token} , oauth_signature=${oauth_signature}`
        }
    }).then(res => {console.dir(res.body); console.log(res.headers)})


    return res.status(200)
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full error?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!!  when I console.log(res.body), { errors: [ { code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.' } ] } show up

Comment: I believe that the parameters need to be sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @AndyPiper Well, it seems its sorted alphabetically!